# VMware crashing when gnome extensions is enabled

Tags: 18.04, vmware, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, vmware-workstation

When I choose some options in VMware Workstation with gnome extensions enabled, VMware crashes... For eg., if I choose "Preferences" or "About VMware Workstation". I have to disable gnome extensions and restart session...

Comment: Disable only one GNOME extension at a time to determine which one is causing your problem. If you provide a list of installed/enabled extensions, maybe I can help identify a bad one. Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/

Comment: Ok, it's GSConnect. When it's enabled AND it's connected to my Android phone, VMware (when I click the options above), crashes...

Answer (score 0):

From the comments...

You've got a GNOME extension problem.

Disable only one GNOME extension at a time to determine which one is causing your problem. If you provide a list of installed/enabled extensions, maybe I can help identify a bad one. Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local

**Update #1:**

It's GSConnect and kdeconnect causing the problem. Remove the extension, and manually uninstall kdeconnect.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little update... It seems it's not the extension "per se". If I re-enable gnome extensions, VMware still crashes when I click the options above.
So, it seems some sort of a compatibility issue...